# Java Bean Validation - Applying Constraints Dynamically

Tags: java

In Java Bean Validation (JSR 303), is there a way to programmatically (dynamically) add constraints in the code before the validate method is called (in addition to the constraints declared as annotations in the bean)?

Comment: The answer to your question is no, but maybe there are other ways to solve your problem if you share your actual usecase.

Comment: Thanks. In my case, the beans are auto generated and I don't have control over their generation and I can't modify them. My workaround was creating a custom validator instead of relying on the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specification says

> This JSR defines a metadata model and API for JavaBean validation. The default metadata source is annotations,
>   with the ability to override and extend the meta-data through the use of XML validation descriptors.

so I guess if any programmatic configuration exists, it is implementation specific and thus nonportable.

Comment: Right. A programmatic configuration is not portable. Hibernate Validator offers a programmatic configuration, but in order to apply constraints dynamically you would have to rebuild the ValidatorFactory all the time, since this is where you specify the configuration.